# pandoc lua filter to apply Quotations style to a Div when converting to docx

Tags: filter, lua, pandoc

I'm using pandoc to convert from latex to docx. In the pandoc AST, the latex \quoting environment is represented by a Div, like this:

```
, Div
    ( "" , [ "quoting" ] , [] )
    [ Para
        [ Str
            "\26377\38065\23601\20986"
        ]
    ]
```

However, this is ignored when writing out the docx file. How do I use a lua filter to apply the Quotations style that's already defined in the reference docx file to the contents of this Div? I have read all the documentation but still lack the necessary info and skill to write the filter myself. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docx writer will use a style if it's passed via the `custom-style` attribute. So a filter like this should work:

```lua
function Div (div)
  if div.classes:includes 'quoting' then
    div.attributes['custom-style'] = 'Quotations'
    return div
  end
end
```